# Selection of a representative operating point for the design of a PID controller for nonlinear systems

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, linear-control

As described in the [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509148/how-to-control-a-nonlinear-system-with-a-pid-controller), there are several ways to control a nonlinear system with a linear PID controller. If no fixed operating point is considered, advanced methods like gain-scheduling should be used.

But what if only one classical PID controller is available? Then a compromise between all possible operating points has to be found. But how to proceed? Do you always use the operating point with the largest static gain as a basis or is there a better way? Is there any literature that deals with this question?

Comment: You could look at the circle criterion.

Comment: you could also see all the nonlinear behavior as an uncertainty and analyze the stability and performance of the closed-loop uncertain system using e.g. robust control theory